# onkeydown not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I have the following javascript in my aspx page.

```
  function isAllowed(evt) {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
      if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 42 && charCode < 47) || (charCode == 36) || charCode == 8)
          return true;
      return false;
  }
```

Then in the vb.aspx file I add the onkeydown attribute.

```
Dim txtDesc As New TextBox
txtDesc.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return isAllowed(event)")
```

This works great in firefox, but it is not working in IE (IE11)

I tried both onkeypress and onkeydown... both works fine in firefox but not IE.

Edit: I found out that it is somewhat working in IE but for the wrong Charcode. My intention is only to allow

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789
and only these symbols +-.,$
```

but on IE. it allows a lot more symbol but disallow some symbols I want. 
for example in IE i cannot type `+-`

in IE I can type `!@#$%^&*()` <-- which supposed to be ignored by the javascript

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at this website : http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Mozilla(FireFox) handles certain keycode differently then IE. Look at the Symbol Keys Table in particular.